# Replace string between first and second occurrence of forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm not very familiar with regex and i need help replacing a string value between the first and second occurrence of forward slash in it.

**Example**

```
const str = '/questions/ask/1'
const strReplace = str.replace(/\[.*?\]\s?/g, 'example')
```

**Output:**

1. `/questions/ask/1` **to** `/example/ask/1`
2. `/questions-math/ask/1` **to** `/example/ask/1`

I can't seem to get right regex.
Thanks for any help. I know there are lot of similar questions but I just could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = '/questions/ask/1';
var s2 = '/questions-math/ask/1';
var r = s.replace(/[^\/][-a-zA-Z]*/, 'example');
var r2 = s2.replace(/[^\/][-a-zA-Z]*/, 'example');
console.log(r);
console.log(r2);
```

**EDIT:**

*The issue of lazy vs greedy.*

For some incomprehensible reason, there is a fashion for using lazy-mode regular expressions. Such expressions are not a panacea for everything. In this case, *the use of default greedy-mode expressions makes them easier to use and develop.*

"Higher performance" is also a myth, just think about the algorithm used but for illustration I compared these solutions by calculating the average of 100 tests each *one million substitutions*:

```
I. 10-year PC, CPU 4 core 23145.70 BogoMIPS
Greedy:  278 ms
Lazy:    900 ms

II. 30-year PC, CPU 1 core 3397.11 BogoMIPS
Greedy:  6736 ms
Lazy:    7490 ms
```

As you can see, the unwavering expression turned out to be slower and this difference drastically increases with the increase in processor power.

Note that these differences relate to 1 million substitutions, with one substitution they have absolutely no meaning.

Naturally, this will not be the case in all cases. *If we care about the performance of a function, there is no shortcut way, the answer will be given only by making measurements by profiling.*

Comment: This works! Is there a way to exclude special characters like if the string has `-` **Example:** `/questions-math/ask/1` **to ** `/example/ask/1`

Comment: Just add these characters to the range of characters that is between [] in this case [-a-zA-Z]

Comment: @Mandy8055 "more efficient", What would the purpose of this 'optimization' be? On my 10-year laptop, 1 million substitutions occurred in 271 ms.

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to use simple JS like this:

```js
var str = '/questions/ask/1';
var res = str.split("/");
res[1] = 'example';
res = res.join("/");
```

Answer (score 2):

If there has to be a second forward slash *present* in the string:

```
^\/[^\/\r\n]+(?=\/)
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `\/` Match the first `/`
- `[^\/\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/` or a newline
- `(?=\/)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is the second `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DOO7Ds/1)

In the replacement use the first `/` followed by `example`

```js
[
  '/questions/ask/1',
  '/questions/',
  '/questions'
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s + " --> " + s.replace(/^\/[^\/\r\n]+(?=\/)/, "/example"))
)
```

Comment: This regex according to me is the most efficient and recommended one here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below regex:

```
^(\/)(?:[-\w!#$]+)(.*?)$
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

> **`^`** - Represents the start of the given string.
>
> **`(\/)`** - Represents **1st** capturing group. This group is used in the replacement as `$1`.
>
> **`(?:[-\w!#$]+)`** - Represents a non-capturing group since you need to replace it containing word characters and all the special symbols that you need to replace **one or more times**. **You can although add other special symbols that you need to exclude here.**
>
> **`(.*?)`** - Represents **2nd** capturing group capturing everything except the new line character **lazily** coming after your replacement. This group is used in the replacement as `$2`.
>
> **`$`** - Represents the end of the given test String.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/AhHVe6/1)

**IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
const regex = /^(\/)(?:[-\w!#$]+)(.*?)$/gm;
const str = `/questions-math/ask/1
/questions/ask/1`;
const subst = `$1examples$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```